# Speeding up calculation using vectors in C++ by using pointers/references

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

Currently, I am making a C++ program that solves a sudoku. In order to do this, I calculate the "energy" of the sudoku (the number of faults) frequently. This calculation unfortunately takes up a lot of computation time. I think that it can be sped up significantly by using pointers and references in the calculation, but have trouble figuring out how to implement this.

In my solver class, I have a `vector<vector<int>` data-member called `_sudoku`, that contains the values of each site. Currently, when calculating the energy I call a lot of functions with pass-by-value. I tried adding a & in the arguments of the functions and a * when making the variables, but this did not work. How can I make this program run faster by using pass-by-reference?

Calculating the energy should not change the vector anyway so that would be better.

I used the CPU usage to track down 80% of the calculation time to the function where vectors are called.

```cpp
int SudokuSolver::calculateEnergy() {
    int energy = 243 - (rowUniques() + colUniques() + blockUniques());//count number as faults
    return energy;
}


int SudokuSolver::colUniques() {
    int count = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < _dim; col++) {
        vector<int> colVec = _sudoku[col];
        for (int i = 1; i <= _dim; i++) {
            if (isUnique(colVec, i)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
int SudokuSolver::rowUniques() {
    int count = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < _dim; row++) {

        vector<int> rowVec(_dim);
        for (int i = 0; i < _dim; i++) {
            rowVec[i] = _sudoku[i][row];
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= _dim; i++) {
            if (isUnique(rowVec, i)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int SudokuSolver::blockUniques() {
    int count = 0;
    for (int nBlock = 0; nBlock < _dim; nBlock++) {
        vector<int> blockVec = blockMaker(nBlock);
        for (int i = 1; i <= _dim; i++) {
            if (isUnique(blockVec, i)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

vector<int> SudokuSolver::blockMaker(int No) {
    vector<int> block(_dim);
    int xmin = 3 * (No % 3);
    int ymin = 3 * (No / 3);
    int col, row;
    for (int i = 0; i < _dim; i++) {
        col = xmin + (i % 3);
        row = ymin + (i / 3);
        block[i] = _sudoku[col][row];
    }
    return block;
}

bool SudokuSolver::isUnique(vector<int> v, int n) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < _dim; i++) {
        if (v[i] == n) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The specific lines that use a lot of computatation time are the ones like:
`vector<int> colVec = _sudoku[col];`
and every time `isUnique()` is called.

I expect that if I switch to using pass-by-reference, my code will speed up significantly. Could anyone help me in doing so, if that would indeed be the case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to use a profiler to see where are the bottlenecks in your application, and make changes to optimize these.

Comment: Step 1) would be to make sure to build your program with the compilers optimizer *enabled*. Step 2) would then be to use a profiler on the *optimized* code to identify where the *actual* bottlenecks are.

Comment: Thanks. I did try doing this, and tracked it down to the lines I mentioned in the last part of my question. I had trouble understanding what changes to make. The already given answers help with that luckily.

Comment: @mand You didn't post the settings you used to compile your program.  Are you running an optimized build, or an unoptimized, "debug" build?  If it is an unoptimized build, please recompile your program to use optimizations and retest.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, thanks for replying. I debug on Windows with Visual Studio. I found out that I had my optimization settings off. Changing it to /O2 improved the speed considerably, though the pass-by-reference change had more effect.

This made me wonder whether compiling and running in cmd differs in run speed from using VS debugging. It does, the command prompt (with /O2) is much speedier even than VS with /O2 . Apparently all the debugging tools slow the process down.

Answer (score 2):

If you change your `SudokuSolver::isUnique` to take `vector<int> &v`, that is the only change you need to do pass-by-reference instead of pass-by-value. Passing with a pointer will be similar to passing by reference, with the difference that pointers could be re-assigned, or be NULL, while references can not.

I suspect you would see some performance increase if you are working on a sufficiently large-sized problem where you would be able to distinguish a large copy (if your problem is small, it will be difficult to see minor performance increases).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Upon further inspection, the most costly part of the function is isUnique(). I have attached the computational profile of that function ![here](https://imgur.com/xExkq0T), but personally do not know how to further optimise this. If anyone else does, I'd be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

`vector<int> colVec = _sudoku[col];` does copy/transfer all the elements, while `const vector<int>& colVec = _sudoku[col];` would not (it only creates an alias for the right hand side).

Same with `bool SudokuSolver::isUnique(vector<int> v, int n) {` versus `bool SudokuSolver::isUnique(const vector<int>& v, int n) {`

Edited after Jesper Juhl's suggestion: The `const` addition makes sure that you don't change the reference contents by mistake.

Edit 2: Another thing to notice is that `vector<int> rowVec(_dim);` these vectors are continuously allocated and unallocated at each iteration, which might get costly. You could try something like

```
int SudokuSolver::rowUniques() {
    int count = 0;
    vector<int> rowVec(_maximumDim); // Specify maximum dimension       
    for (int row = 0; row < _dim; row++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _dim; i++) {
            rowVec[i] = _sudoku[i][row];
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= _dim; i++) {
            if (isUnique(rowVec, i)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

if that doesn't mess up with your implementation.

Comment: You may want to sprinkle a bit of `const` in there. ;)

Comment: This, like @CoffeeBeforeArch's comment, made a huge difference! The code now runs about ~100/~1000 times faster. Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction and helping me out!

Comment: @Tetix, your Edit 2 suggestion also works, and it's not noticeable much, but probably makes a little difference. Since the values are overwritten each time anyway it makes no difference for the implementation.